# Using Boostrap I'd like to scale images to min height on smaller devices

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a graphic design portfolio site live built with bootstrap http://www.burnser.com/index.html

On large and mid-size screens the full-width images look great. But when viewed on smaller devices the images are too small. This uses the class:

```
.img-responsive {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Is there a way to scale the images on smaller devices to a min height (about 400px) and then crop the sides of the image focusing on the centre of the image?

Comment: Use media queries to define the style you want. You can set styles based on the screen size.

Comment: With only CSS it is not possible to crop the images. You either need wrapping elements or background-images.

Comment: How can it be done using a wrapping element Huelfe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to target a specific device.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Then you can apply different width / height to the image depending on the device.

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .img-responsive {
        width: //something;
        height: //something;
    }
}
```